# Minimum Values to Cause idiv Instruction to Overflow in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm writing a program to practice some reverse engineering techniques.  Here are the relevant lines of x86 (Intel) assembly code:

```
mov, eax [ebp - 20]
cdq
idiv ecx
```

Through my input (a network socket) I can control the bytes that go into `eax` and `ecx` before these lines of assembly are executed.

My question is: what are the minimum values (positive or negative) that I can use in order to cause division overflow (where division overflow is NOT a "divide by zero" error but where a result is returned that is greater than 32-bits and, therefore, will not fit into `eax` (the return register).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: There is no such input, all results will fit. Actually maybe `-2^31 / -1` won't :)

Comment: @harold I think I'd like to define minimum as the smallest positive or negative value s.t. overflow occurs.  As a complete false and contrived example: if 0xff/3 and 0xff/2 both caused overflow, I would consider 0xff/2 to be the minimum.

Comment: @Jester I'll have to think about your suggestion there but division overflow can definitely happen when dividing a 64-bit quantity by a 32-bit quantity.  This is not the case for multiplication though.

Comment: Except this is a 32 bit division. Performed on a 64 bit sign-extended dividend, but still a 32 bit division in effect.

Answer (score 6):

Since your dividend is 32 bits and it is sign extended to 64 bits by the `cdq` the only way to get an overflow is due to the asymmetry of two's complement, namely that it can represent `-2^31` but not `+2^31`. As such, you can do `-2^31 / -1`.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking it had to happen along one of those byte boundaries.  Since the MSB is being used as the sign bit, when we count from 2^n -1 to 2^n, in the unsigned case we'd be fine but in the signed case we're inadvertently flipping the sign bit and this is where the overflow happens.  You are exactly right, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @jkovba Note that this calculation, because it doesn't fit into the destination operand, will generate a divide error exception. This is the same exception that's generated when dividing by 0.

Comment: @RossRidge That's exactly what I'm looking for!  I'm using Python to send bytes over a socket and I'm looking to make a specific method crash by generating an exception by causing in 'idiv' instruction to overflow EAX.